# Trying to implement in-app voice call from browser

Tags: call, voice, vonage

I have cloned the click-to-call repository and followed the steps as mentioned. I am able to login with said created user but then get stuck at /rtc API.I got some error in network panel. and "General SSL engine problem in console which is not correct. SSL certificates are all correct." Let me know where i went wrong. Please check the screenshot below :

[image]

I have had a talk with nexmo team, they said it is the ssl issue. 
https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/207051767-Certificate-for-nexmo-com

Now I am unable to find where to import the certificate to my app?

Answer (score 2):

I am the JavaScript Developer Advocate at Vonage (Nexmo).

You also filed an issue at https://github.com/nexmo-community/client-sdk-click-to-call correct? Thanks for that. I will also post my response here.

From your issue, it looks as if the Conversation Id is not being sent.

We recently merged some changes to the repo.
In your .env file, do you have `SUPPORT_PHONE_NUMBER`? That should be `NEXMO_NUMBER`.

Also, when calling the server, previously the code in the client.js around line 34 was `application.callServer();` it is now `application.callServer(application.me.name);`

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hello, I have already made all the above changes. Here are some conversations ID : 
CON-3e319b43-f792-4870-9bd5-e89060c4d201
CON-ae257d92-4670-45a7-8231-89a823de7b3b

Here, the link which i received from them regarding the SSL general engine problem: 
https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/207051767-Certificate-for-nexmo-com
but not sure, where too import the provided certificate at.

Comment: Hi @Priyanka Hmmm. If the problem is with SSL, I don't think the issue is with your application but with the server you are using which I'm assuming is ngrok since that is what is used in the repo. 

Whenever I need to update my SSL certificate, I do it on my server.

With that in mind, I found this article on our blog [Connect your local development server to the Nexmo API using an ngrok tunnel](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/07/04/local-development-nexmo-ngrok-tunnel-dr). 

Also did some searching for ngrok and SSL that lead me to their [docs](https://ngrok.com/docs#tls) under TLS.

Comment: As an alternative, I've used [Glitch](https://glitch.com/) to build test projects using our APIs. Not sure if that's an available option for you.

If it is, and you give it a try, I would be interested to see if you got it working.

Comment: I have tried over live server as well. and Issue remains the same.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Was your live server using https or http? Trying to see if SSL is the issue. 

We are also working on a tutorial that allows a user to call themselves. I can share that with you if you would like and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is now resolved by appending the chain certificate path in the code.

Comment: That's awesome! Glad you were able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Nexmo - either you are out of balance or your account has been been marked inactive for some reason. Most of the time its because of insufficient balance.

Comment: No. I have 3 Euros balance. and how to check inactive account?

Comment: Go to the Nexmo dashboard and check under account details. If you do have sufficient balance, I suggest you speak with their tech support.

Comment: I asked the tech team and they have shared the link : https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/207051767-Certificate-for-nexmo-com
Link says to import the given certificate to your application. But I am unable to figure out where to import it.